# How do I change state on a component two levels up?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and I've started extracting components. I understand how to bind an event like `onClick` on a child component, but what about a grandchild?

Example:

I have a `List` component. It has `ListRow` children. Within each ListRow child, I have a button component for deleting that particular row from the parent (`List). My thoughts are that the`deleteRow`click handler would be on the`List`component so that I could then set the state. However, I can't seem to find a way to call the grandparent's (`List`) eventHandler.

```
<List /> // has event handler as well as state for the list items
    <ListRow />
        <DeleteButton /> //when clicking this i want to delete parent <ListRow />
```

Am I just supposed to pass the onclick down the chain?

Comment: have you tried passing down methods?

Comment: Trying it currently. Well, fumbling with it currently rather. I don't know if I have the syntax right.

Comment: Passing down methods is definitely a way of doing things though as you get into more complex "passing downs" (like trying to update components with very distant common ancestors) you may want to take a look at Redux. Redux is a state management library that can be used in conjunction with React.

Comment: Yes, Redux is definitely the next step in creating more complex sites

Comment: Thanks for the comments. If my project gets too complex I'll look into Redux for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating components you have to decide whether or not a component is a functional component or a component that needs to manage state. Here is an example where you have a "Grandparent" that passes down functionality to it's child and the child to it's child. If a component does not need to manage state you make it a "functional component" like the "Parent" and "Child" examples below:

```
class GrandParent extends Component {
  handleState = (obj) => {
    this.setState(obj);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Parent handleState={this.handleState} />
    );
  }
}

function Parent(props) {
  render() {
    return (
      <Child handleState={props.handleState} />
    );
  }
}
  function Child(props) {
    render() {
      return (
        ...
      );
    }
  }
```

You want to pass it down along and wherever you need to call the function you can use it as `props.handleState()` from whatever component that you send it to.

Comment: Aha! So you do pass it down. I think I was trying to do onClick={this.onClick}. Does it have to be functional? I thought that functional and class based were just two different ways of writing the components. I didn't think it really mattered which version was used.

Comment: When creating a component, ask yourself if it needs to manage state or not. For example, let's say you had a navigation component that needed to highlight the link that is active, this would be a good candidate for state and be better as a stateful component vs. a functional component. If "Parent" and "Child" need to manage state, you can change them to stateful components.

Comment: Is this just a best practice? The documentation states that they are the same from React's point of view. Classes have some additional features though. So like you said, if it manages state, it would need to be class. But, if it doesn't manage state it can still be a class.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something this:

```
// grandparent function that goes into parent
heirloom() 
{
    console.log("grandparent says hi");
    //something happens
}

// everything else (put into all subsequent children)
heirloom()
{
    this.props.heirloom();
}

<List heirloom="this.heirloom">
    <ListRow heirloom="this.heirloom" />
        <DeleteButton onClick="this.heirloom"/>
```

My syntax may be off and this may or may not work, I haven't had the chance to play around with React for a while. If it does, great! If it doesn't, let's just hope someone with a better answer comes along ^^

Comment: You've got the right idea. As you said, syntax is just a little off.

Comment: @JamesGanong Feel free to post an accurate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)