# ReactJS: Parent component re-rendering from change in child

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, meteor

Setup in parent component as default class extending component:

```
renderChildren() {
  let children = Mongo.Collection.find().fetch(); // array of objects
  return children.map((child) => (
    <Child key={child._id} child={child} />
  ));
}

<Parent>
  {this.renderChildren()}
</Parent>
```

... in the child component

```
toggleStatus() {
  //changes the status on collection
  Meteor.call('changeStatus', this.props.child._id, this.props.child.status); 
}
render() {
  return (
    <span onClick={this.toggleStatus.bind(this)}>Change Status</span>
  )
}
```

Problem: entire parent is re-rendered every time a child changes status. Makes sense...

How can I only re-render the child, not the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to solve this problem that I can think of:

1. Give the child component state by making it a class and having it extend React.Component. I personally would do option two
2. Pass toggleStatus to the child from the parent and use that to set state in the child.

[I answered this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42798938/how-do-i-change-state-on-a-component-two-levels-up/42799200#42799200) regarding parent and children components that might give you a better idea of how to pass it down.

Comment: Okay, here's what I tried. In the parent component, under the extends `TrackerReact(Component) {` I have my function: `handleStatus(e){ Meteor.call('toggleStatus', e.categoryName, e._id, e.status); }`
Then, in my `collectionFunction() { return posts.map((post)=>(<ChildComponent key{post._id} handleStatus={this.handleStatus(post)} />));}` Then in my child component `return ( <span onClick={this.props.handleStatus.bind(this)}></span>)` The problem, all the functions fire as soon as it renders... thoughts?

Comment: Okay, I stopped it from firing immediately by changing the child component to `<ChildComponent... handleStatus={()=>this.handleStatus(post)} />));}` but the parent is being re-rendered again... would using state make a difference?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand, maybe, what to do: inside my child component `class Child extends Component { constructor(props) { super(props); this.state = this.props.child }` okay, this will set the state of every child component to the object passed to it from parent... Inside the child, I can just reflect the state of the child. When I click the button, it should change the state of status of the child and update the database... does that sound right?

Comment: Okay, figured it out. It was TrackerReact that was doing the rerendering... grrrrr....

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out, I hope that I was able to help you!